# search in a view string with '*' in it

Tags: xpages

I have an xpage where I'm looking in a view for products where the productname itself (viewScope.product) contains in it's name sometime a '*' for example productname 'apple 2 * d1' and productname 'apple 3 * p' and productname 'apple 2' etc

I don't succeed in obtaining the correct viewresults for the selected product (viewScope.product)

PS the search is an array since I have other selection criteria which do work

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="viewPictures"
        databaseName="product/demo.nsf" viewName="demo3">
        <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:var tmpArray = new Array("");
    var cTerms = 0;
    tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(FIELD Prod = \"" + viewScope.product + "\")";
    return tmpArray.toString();
    return qstring
    ]]></xp:this.search>
    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ? as a replacement for any one character when doing full text search.

E.g.
FIELD Prod = "apple 2 ? d1"

If there are documents that contains other combinations, e.g. "apple t X d1", this would be included in the search.
I don't know of a way to escape * in full text search.